# So I've stored an NSDictionary object in an NSMutableArray, how do I know use the NSDictionary keys to grab these objects out of the array?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I have two `UISlider`'s that represent minimum and maximum prices of items. I am passing these as well as other various data back to the previous controller.

I've used a protocol method and set the previous controller as a delegate to make it possible to pass values back to the controller.

**I can easily grab the other objects out of the array because they're strings. I just use:**

```
     [_finalSelectionForRefinement containsObject:@"size"];
```

**This is what I do in pushed controller:**

```
      // create dictionary with keys minimum and maximum that hold the 
      // position of the slider as a float  

      _dictionaryWithSliderValues = 
      [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:_minSliderPosition], @"minimum",
      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:_maxSliderPosition], @"maximum", nil];

      // store this in the array that is retrieved in previous controller
      [_finalSelectionForRefinement addObject:_dictionaryWithSliderValues];
```

My question is how do I now use the minimum and maximum keys to grab the slider position float objects?

Thought I could use NSPredicate but the examples I've been coming across on blogs as well as youTube are of no help to my specific needs.

Would appreciate some help here

Regards

**UPDATE - Short snipped of method in previous controller where I need to retrieve the slider minimum and maximum values:**

```
-(PFQuery *)queryForCollection
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Garments"];

        if (_selectedRowInFilterPicker == 0) {
            NSLog(@"ORDER BY RECOMMENDED");
            [query orderByDescending:@"recommended"];
        } else if (_selectedRowInFilterPicker == 1) {
            NSLog(@"ORDER BY NEWEST ITEMS");
            [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
        } else if (_selectedRowInFilterPicker == 2) {
            NSLog(@"ORDER BY DESCENDING USING PRICE");
            [query orderByDescending:@"price"];
        } else if (_selectedRowInFilterPicker == 3) {
            NSLog(@"ORDER BY ASCENDING USING PRICE");
            [query orderByAscending:@"price"];
        }


        if ([_selectionFromRefineResultsController count] > 0) {
            NSLog(@"Selection FROM REF MADE");

            // Gender
            if ([_selectionFromRefineResultsController containsObject:@"Male"]) {
                [query whereKey:@"gender" equalTo:@1];
            }
            if ([_selectionFromRefineResultsController containsObject:@"Female"]) {
                [query whereKey:@"gender" equalTo:@2];
            }
        }

        // Here I need to check there is a minimum or maximum value in the array
        // If there is I can user [query whereKey:@"price" greaterThan:MINVAL] and MAXVAL
        // This will return items within the correct price range.
```

This queryForCollection method is called from within another method called performQuery which is called when the button of the second controller is tapped to pass data back to the controller that pushed it in the first place.

Comment: Post your code where you need to use these values. You should have everything setup except the details of actually doing the filtering.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't make the _finalSelectionForRefinement a dictionary?  Are there other dictionaries in _finalSelectionForRefinement besides _dictionaryWithSliderValues?

Comment: @rmaddy The code would be useless as all it is a method with several calls to my array e.g. [_finalSelectionForRefinement containsObject:@"colour"];, [_finalSelectionForRefinement containsObject:@"size"]; etc. Because this particular object I'm working with is not a string I can't search for it this way.

Comment: Ethan I didn't make _finalSelectionForRefinement an NSDictionary because 90% of the objects I'm storing inside it are strings that I can use to identify each object. It made more sense to use an NSMutableArray. A dictionary would work though wouldn't it. Hmm, would be last resort as I'd have to refactor a big bunch of code.

Comment: @LondonGuy I'm not sure I understand what you're doing...  What good does checking whether the array contains @"size" do if you there's no other value associated with that string?

Comment: I need the values to perform a query. I take the min slider value and the max slider value (0 to 300) and use that in a query to the database to return items within a price range. All I need is to be able to read those values. I've added more code to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the documentation for [NSMutableArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) , [NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) and [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Which will explain the instance methods for each.

But in a nutshell any object that you add should be in a NSDictionary so it has a value and a key. This includes any of your strings. Doing so simplifies how you search by using keys.

If the NSMutableArray contains objects that are not KVC then you will I think find it harder it go through the objects in one sweep.

Because NSmutableArray inherites from NSArray you can then use instance method **valueForKey:** on a NSmutableArray whose objects values  or objects objects values have keys.

> ***valueForKey:***
>
> Returns an array containing the results of invoking
> valueForKey: using key on each of the array's objects.
>
> - (id)valueForKey:(NSString *)key

Rough Example:

```
  NSMutableArray * finalSelectionForRefinement =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  NSDictionary *dictionaryWithSliderValues = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:10], @"minimum", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:20], @"maximum", nil];
    
     NSDictionary *stringValues = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"the-size", @"size", @"the-hight", @"hight", nil];
    
  
    [finalSelectionForRefinement addObject:dictionaryWithSliderValues];
     [finalSelectionForRefinement addObject:stringValues];
    
    
    
    
    NSLog(@"finalSelectionForRefinement = %@", [finalSelectionForRefinement valueForKey:@"maximum"] );
```

First off, you can of store everything in one NSDictionary which makes more sense. But I wanted to show you that the ***valueForKey:*** will search within each.

The other thing is ***valueForKey:*** will return an NSArray containing the results. any objects that it finds that do not match the key you are looking for will be returned as an NSNull object. i.e

```
finalSelectionForRefinement = (
    20,
"<null>"
)
```

So you would need to still single your value out. One way is use a **objectEnumerator** like this:

```
 NSEnumerator *enumerator = [[finalSelectionForRefinement valueForKey:@"maximum"] objectEnumerator];
    id anObject;
    
    while (anObject = [enumerator nextObject]) {
       
        if(![anObject  isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
         {
          NSLog(@"anObject = %@", anObject);
        }
       
    }
```

Which should return:

```
 anObject = 20
```

There are most likely better ways of doing this. All of the above is just to give you one idea.  And I suspect you could cut out a lot of the code by using bindings.

(also note this answer was being constructed before you question update)

Comment: This let me to my answer. I converted the NSMutablearray to a NSMutabledictionary. Stored everything as NSMutableDictionaries. Retrieved using valueForKey. Retrieved the float NSNumber objects using objectForKey calling "floatValue" stored in a var. Then checked value was greater than 0. If it was that meant slider was moved so must have a value. Added the value or values as part of my query. Works perfectly.